# How to remove white spaces in the beginning and the end in matlab?

Tags: matlab, cell, removing-whitespace

I have a structure consisting of cells. I want to remove all white spaces in the beginning of each cell and in the end, and I want to preserve all the white spaces in between text in the cells. So if I have

```
s = '   bbb b bbbb   '
```

I want to obtain

```
s = 'bbb b bbbb'
```

I want to apply this method to an unknown number of cells in this structure (for example 2x3), perhaps using a loop. Does anyone have an idea how to do it? I failed with `regexp`.

Comment: now I got a simple yet useful answer: strtrim(s)! How can I apply it for each cell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `strtrim()` in combination with `structfun()` and cell-indexing:

```
your_struct = structfun(@(x) strtrim(x{1}), your_struct);
```

This only works if your struct has a layout like

```
your_struct.a = {' some string  '};
your_struct.b = {' some other string  '};
...
```

If it has a different structure, say,

```
your_struct.a = { {' some string  '}
                  {'   some other string '}};

your_struct.b = { {' again, some string  '}
                  {'   again, some other string '}};

...
```

You could try

```
your_struct = structfun(@(x) ...
    cellfun(@strtrim, x, 'uni', false), ...
    your_struct, 'uni', false);
```

Comment: I have a cell lets say 10x2. each cell contains a string with white spaces in the beginning, middle and end, want to remove all apart from these in the beginning. so it's like **my_cell{1,1} = ' name1   '** **my_cell{1,2} = ' string1'** **my_cell{2,1} = ' new name2  '** etc. What would be the simpliest solution that would do this? yours I didn't manage to apply unfortunatelly ..

Comment: @user1578163 What do you get when you apply my solution? Does it give an error? Could you perhaps edit your question to include a minimal working version of your structure+cell?

Comment: sure, thanks: my working example is **M = {'  title1' ' my name1   '; 'title2' 'my name2   '}** what I get when I apply your solution: Inputs to STRUCTFUN must be scalar structures.

Comment: @user1578163 If that's true, then you don't have a structure -- just a cell. In matlab, these mean very different things. For your case, the answer provided by tomelse should suffice. I've edited it so it should work when you copy-pase it now.

Comment: problem solved: **result = cellfun(@strtrim, M,'UniformOutput',false)**

Comment: I didn't see your comment now. Yes, you're right. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If your matrix is called a, do:

```
 newmatrix = cellfun(@strtrim, a, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

Comment: and how can I apply this for each cell efficiently? Because writing this function at the very end doesn't remove.

Comment: what do you mean by each cell?

Comment: with cellfun? so TrimmedCellMatrix = cellfun(@strtrim, OriginalMatrix)

Comment: The OP indicates that there are many cells in his structure.  `structfun` should be used instead of `cellfun`.

Answer (score 0):

If `A` is your structure containing the cells, then you could do:

```
New_A=structfun(@strtrim,A,'UniformOutput',false)
```

Answer (score 0):

strtrim doesn't alway take care of the end of the string for me, so I use [deblank](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/deblank.html)

so if strtrim didn't do everything you wanted, you can use that in conjunction with deblank to get what you want.